# spy on observable inside method

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular2-observables

I want to verify that this.isLoggedIn is set by calling retrieveToken.

I would also like to spy on `this.authService.currentToken`, is that possible or is there another way of verifying that observables have been subscribed to?

**component**

```
 public retrieveToken(): void {
        this.authService.currentToken
          .subscribe(status => {
            if (status) {
              this.isLoggedIn = true;
            }
          });
      }
```

**service**

```
export class AuthenticationService {
    public currentTokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>;
    public currentToken: Observable<any>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.currentTokenSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any> ());
        this.currentToken = this.currentTokenSubject.asObservable();
    }

}
```

**spec**

```
 it('', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    const tokenSpy = spyOn(authService, 'currenToken').and.returnValue(of({}));
    app.retrieveToken();
    expect(tokenSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

**error message**

> Error:  : currenToken() method does not exist 
>       Usage: spyOn(, )

Comment: spyOn is used to mock method calls. Your currentToken is a property. If you would have a get accessor than you could use spyOnProperty. Since this is not the case you could create a mock class or property which you then provide inside the TestBed of your spec file for the real AuthService using the {provide: Service, useClass/useMethod MockService}

Answer (score 0):

You could define service mock inside your test spec file, like this:

```
class AuthenticationServiceMock extends AuthenticationService {
   // here you can define what you need, in your case it is currentToken
   // which you need 
}
```

then in TestBed where you are setting your providers, you need to specify that you want to use that mock class you created

```
providers: [
            {
                provide: AuthenticationService,
                useValue: new AuthenticationServiceMock()
            },
            ]
```

Now inside of your test case when you call "app.retrieveToken();"
currentToken should be available.

I hope this will help you :)